# @StateObject Not Updating

Tags: swiftui

Hobbyist here and I'm trying to learn SwiftUI. Using UIKit I wrote a weather app (got geo location, downloaded json from openwetherapi, decoded it and updated my display, and refreshed when it returned from the background) and now trying to port over to SwiftUI. I am stuck on two problems that I believe are similar. When my app returns to foreground I want it to refresh itself, and I want a button to also force a refresh. Here is my StartingView.

```
struct StartingView: View {
@StateObject private var internetConnection = TestNetStatus()
@StateObject private var geoLocation = LocationManager()
@State var reloadFlag: Bool = false

let LM1 = LocationManager()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if !internetConnection.connected {
            NoConnectivityView()
        } else if geoLocation.geoLatitude == 0.0 {
                NoGeoCoords()
        } else {
            VStack {
                Text(String(reloadFlag))
                Text("Remote test flag from LocationManager = " + String(geoLocation.testFlag))
                Text("Current Date " + geoLocation.strDateTime)
                Text("Lat = " + String(geoLocation.geoLatitude))
                Text("Long = " + String(geoLocation.geoLongitude))
                Text("City = " + geoLocation.strCity)
                Text("Region = " + geoLocation.strRegion)

                Button("Update") {
                    reloadFlag.toggle()
                    LM1.updateDateTime()
                    LM1.updateTestFlg()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Basically, I check for internet connectivity with TestNetStatus, then get latitude, longitude and decode them into city and region in LocationManager.

Here is my LocationManager (I'm not bothering to show the location management funcs, just the parts that I can't make work right now).

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@Published var geoLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
@Published var geoLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
@Published var strCity: String = ""
@Published var strRegion: String = ""
@Published var strDateTime: String = ""    
@Published var testFlag: Bool = false

let manager = CLLocationManager()
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    updateDateTime()
    
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    print("started location services")
}

func updateTestFlg() {
    self.testFlag.toggle()
}

func updateDateTime() {
    let df1 = DateFormatter()
    df1.dateFormat = "E MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a"
    self.strDateTime =  df1.string(from: Date())
    print("Getting date and time ", self.strDateTime)

}
```

When I click on the button I call a function in LocationManager to update the date and time and since this is a published var that is a @StateObject in my StartingView, I would have expected the display to refresh with the new date/time (and also any new location info if it had changed). I know my function is working but the display is not updating.

I have searched through the Stack Overflow questions related to this type of problem but not found my answer. I have a feeling that I'm missing something very basic, but I have struggled with this issue for over a week and my forehead is bleeding from all the brick walls I've bumped into. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `StartingView`, try removing `let LM1 = LocationManager()`, and use `geoLocation` where you used `LM1`. Currently you have 2 `LocationManager()` that have no relations to each other. Use only `geoLocation` .

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the trick. Very much appreciate your help!